# Как достать 3 последних объекта из базы данных?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть база данных posts , с нее я достаю объекты через map() , но как достать только 3 последних поста ?

```
const { posts } = useSelector((state) => state.posts);

{posts.items.map((obj) =>
            (
              <Post
                id={obj._id}
                title={obj.title}
                text={obj.text}
                user={obj.user}
                episode={obj.episode}
                imageUrl={obj.imageUrl ? `${'http://localhost:4444'}${obj.imageUrl}` : ''}
                audioUrl={obj.audioUrl ? `${'http://localhost:4444'}${obj.audioUrl}` : ''}
                tags={obj.tags}
              />
            ),
          )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
posts.items.slice(-3).map и т.д.
```

Метод *slice* возвращает новый массив, содержащий последние три элемента исходного массива (с индекса -3 и до конца массива)